# jQuery AJAX response JSON get child node

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

i am trying to take the responseJSON from an AJAX call and just extract one element to the variable formDigestValue.  I have tried about a dozen ways of trying to return the response, using JSON.parse(), $.parseJSON() and some others, but there are 2 main issues that i cant seem to figure out.  I put in a check for if (data.lenght > 0){do something}, response.length, responseJSON, jqXHR, XHR, i cant seem to find the variable that holds the data that would end up sent to success function.  I've tried just setting the ajax call to a variable (var y = $.ajax()...) and manipulating it that way.

I just keep reading different articles and trying different ways, but nothing seems to quite get it right and it seems to be fairly simple, but i feel like im just missing something simple on this.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var siteURL = "xxx";
        var formDigestValue = "";

        jQuery.ajax({
                url: siteURL + "/_api/contextinfo",
                type: "POST",
                headers: { 
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function(){
                    contextHeaders = $.parseJSON(responseJSON);
                    formDigestValue = contextHeaders.FormDigestValue;
                }
            });
...
```

any advice would be greatly appreciated.  For reference, the JSON returned looks like the below.  i am trying to figure out if i also need anything extra to get at child nodes, as it looks like it comes back buried a bit (i broke it out with indents just to show the depth):

```
{
    "d":
    {
        "GetContextWebInformation":
        {
            "__metadata":
            {
                "type":"SP.ContextWebInformation"
            },
            "FormDigestTimeoutSeconds":1800,
            "FormDigestValue":"0xADC9732A0652EF933F4dfg1EF9C1B75131456123492CFFB91233261B46F58FD40FF980C475529B663CC654629826ECBACA761558591785D7BA7F3B8C62E2CB72,26 Jun 2015 21:20:10 -0000",
            "LibraryVersion":"15.0.4631.1000",
            "SiteFullUrl":"http://example.com/",
            "SupportedSchemaVersions":
            {
                "__metadata":
                {
                    "type":"Collection(Edm.String)"
                },
                "results":["14.0.0.0","15.0.0.0"]
            },
            "WebFullUrl":"http://www.example.cm"
        }
    }
}
```

### edit 6/27

Alright, I think between the comment on accessing the child nodes and the rest on passing the argument to success function, ive almost go it.  My main thing is, I cannot seem to pass it as an argument. I tried to say it initially, but dont think I write the explanation properly.  I tried:

`Success: function(responseJSON)...`

As well as

`Success: function(data)...`

But the data never seems to actually enter the function,  its null values.  I know the json returned, but having issues passing it into success function

Here is a look at firebug when this runs:
[image: Function Error]

Comment: What you're looking for it seems (following the object structure) is `contextHeaders.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue`. You could just iterate through the object looking for the property but that's where it's currently at.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add dataType option with json value and don't forget the callback success function take at least one parameter which is the data returned by the server.

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: siteURL + "/_api/contextinfo",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: { 
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting from my iPhone, so, it's hard. From the first look, you're not capturing the returned result in success. Try the following.

success: function(responseJSON) { 
    contextHeaders = $.parseJSON(responseJSON);

Answer (score 0):

if that block of json is what you get returned by `$.parseJSON(responseJSON)` then you're right, you just need to dig a bit deeper:

```
           contextHeaders = $.parseJSON(responseJSON);
           formDigestValue = contextHeaders.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;
```

hope that helps :)